# Closed subsets of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> $X=\{(a,b)\mid a \in C[0,1],b \in C[0,1]\}$, and its norm is $\|(a,b)\|=\|a\|_\infty+\|b\|_\infty.$
>
> $Y=\{(a,a')\mid a \in C^1[0,1], \ a'(t)=\frac{da}{dt} \},\ Z=\{(0,b)\mid b \in C[0,1]\}.$
>
> Under these conditions, Please show that $Y+Z=\{y+z \mid y \in Y, z \in Z\}$ is not a closed subset of $X$

(I have already known that $X$ is Banach space, and $Y,Z$ are closed subsets of $X$.)

I have to say that there is one sequence $\{y_n+z_n \mid y_n \in Y, z_n \in Z\}$ which converges to $(y,z) \notin Y+Z$. But what kind of sequence will suffice above?

Comment: Is your $T$ supposed to be $Z$?

Comment: Notice $Y+Z = C^1[0,1]\times C[0,1]$ and that $C^1[0,1]$ is not closed in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I fixed $T \rightarrow Z$. Thanks for indicating my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $(a,a')\in Y$, we have that $(0,-a')\in Z$. So $(a,0)\in Y+ Z$. In other words, $Y+Z$ contains the subspace $W=\{(a,0):\ a\in C^1[0,1]\}$.

So now we need a Cauchy sequence in $W$ that is not convergent in $W$. For instance  $\{(a_n,0)\}$, where $a_n(t)=(t+1/n)^{1/2}$.

Comment: it must converge in $X$. it does not converge in $W$

Comment: It does converge in $X$. It converges to $a(t)=t^{1/2}$.

Comment: So $(a_n(t),a_n'(t))$ that is not convergent in $Y$ is in $Y$?(which means Y is not a closed subset of X???)

Comment: The sequence $(a_n,a_n') $ is in $Y $, but it is not Cauchy. It tells you nothing about the closedness of $Y $.